# wix custom dialog for config edit

Tags: wix, dialog, config

hi i'm trying make a setup msi for my application with wix v3
I have a problem about this task;
I need a user input that will be stored in my application's config file
(for example i need a dialog for sql connection string and the user input will be written in application config file.)

I tried to google but got nothing worked

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do three things:

1. Create a custom property:

   ```
   <Wix>
    <Product ...>
      <Property Id="SQLSERVER" /> ... 
    </Product>
   </Wix>
   ```
2. Add a custom dialog to your Wix UI to capture the user input and store it to a property. This [tutorial](http://clarify.dovetailsoftware.com/kmiller/2009/11/04/adding-a-custom-dialog-to-your-wix-installer/) should help you with that.
3. In the component that installs your web.config file, use the XmlFile element to update your web.config with the value of your property:

   ```
    <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateConnectionStringInConfigSection" File="[ROOT_DRIVE]inetpub/wwwroot/$(var.ProductName)/web.config" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name=&quot;ConnectionString&quot;[\]]/@connectionString" Value="[SQLSERVER]" Permanent="yes" />
   ```

Comment: Where does <util:XmlFile> come from?  It does not show in my VS2010 intellisense.

Comment: Got it.  Add reference to WixUtilExtension DLL and also include the namespace in the XML <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

Comment: If it helps anyone else, to expand on Andez's comment above, I had to use the following line to define the namespace (adding in the http:// and removing the semicolon): `<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">`