# Visual Studio WIX Application deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I have created an application & and a MSI file using WIX. I have installed the application on my friends computer. However he is not able to edit the config file. It says "Access Denied". How do I make the config file editable?

Comment: Are you talking about a .NET config file (e.g. Application1.exe.config, which is often a copy of the app.config in a VS .NET project)? Users don't normally need to edit config files. What content in the config file were you looking to edit?

Comment: Yes a .Net config file. Its my app.config file. I know normally I wouldn't want users to change my config file however for this one of I do. I was just looking to change the connection string. I know I can do this in the code but I am now intrigued to figure out how to enable a user to edit the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three reasonable, non-exclusive approaches:

1. Allow the installing administrator to enter a [connection string during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1742879/2226988).
2. Install the application with the [per-user InstallScope](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) instead of per-machine.
3. Use a [user-scoped configuration settin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)g and provide a means for the user to change and save it through the application.

Giving users [write access](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/permissionex.html) to a machine-wide app.config file is not the way to go. It's too powerful.

I typically use the last one or both the last two.

Comment: I agree that giving users write access to the app.config file is not the way to go. This is however just a one-off situation and would like to know how. I have gone with the third option you listed, thanks